# Microsoft VB.NET 2010 - Assigning a Key to start a process when the window is minimized

Tags: vb.net, button, key, assign

This is an auto talker that i created, but it isn't very convenient to click on start and stop when the text is being typed at 10 milliseconds. So i wanted to create a key that when pressed starts the auto typer, and also stops it. I have a box where the user can press a key to assign to start and stop the auto typing. What code would i put for clicking on assign? I want assign to: get key from textbox5.text and use it as the shortcut key to start spamming. The key would be pressed when the Interface for the spam bot is minimized, so i can't use "&Spambot" for S to be the shortcut key.
Any help would be appreciated.
Please click on the link below to see image

http://s16.postimg.org/6xdxtjvg5/Interface.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully used some methods to read the numkey state, started my stuff when it is turned on, and stop it when it is turned off again, maybe you will like that solution.

```
If Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) Then ...
```

your alternative would be to 1. use an keyDown event (i think it gave more information about pressed keys than key pressed event), then store it in a local variable

And finally using an external dll to figure out if any key is pressed anywhere in windows. And if, then compare if it is the correct key, and then trigger whatever you want to trigger.

Comment: could i please add you on skype? I'm relatively new to .VB and would need your help in the future! :)

Comment: i updated my profile, sure, but i cannot guaantee to help for a long time every day. and i guess i should be online in skype then :)